# Received fatal alert: handshake_failure on Java 1.7

Tags: java, ssl

I have this SSL issue, I get handshake_failure

```
http-bio-8080-exec-10, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 191
http-bio-8080-exec-10, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
http-bio-8080-exec-10, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
http-bio-8080-exec-10, called closeSocket()
http-bio-8080-exec-10, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Keep-Alive-Timer, called close()
Keep-Alive-Timer, called closeInternal(true)
Keep-Alive-Timer, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
Keep-Alive-Timer, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 48
Keep-Alive-Timer, called closeSocket(selfInitiated)
```

Code is Working with no issue on java version "1.8.0_05"
But same code with same SSL certificates is not working on java version "1.7.0_67"

I installed unlimited Crypto on the 1.7 and still facing the same issue.
Unfortunately I cannot upgrade the JDK, Is there any other way around this issue?

Comment: Do you have logs on server side to better understand what is happening? As the last resort, sniff the exchanges with both Java version and try to find out what is different.